# Put input value back to input filed

Tags: php, forms, session

I have two submit buttons in one form and when I used the first submit, all the text input fields become blank. I try to solve this by using a session to store the textfield inputs.However, I don't know how I can put back the value to the input field that I stored in the session after the first submit is used.

The HTML code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="text" name="headline" id="headline" required />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Images" name="submit_image"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit_post" value="Submit Your Post"/>
</form>
```

The php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["submit_image"])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['headline'])) {
       $_SESSION["headline_session"] = $_POST ["headline"]; 
    }
}
$headline_session = $_SESSION["headline_session"];
?>
```

Comment: Try to use ajax here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want to use a session! 
you can echo the value of $post parameter in a property called (value) like this

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="text" name="headline" id="headline" value="<?php echo $_POST ['headline']; ?>" required />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Images" name="submit_image"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit_post" value="Submit Your Post"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to first check the value with isset?

Comment: Sure, just I gave a headline to use value .. 
although we can use @$_POST ['headline']  to avoid PHP warnings

Comment: If the type is a checkbox not a text field, how do I keep track of the previous choice?

Comment: The you can do this : 
<type="checkbox" name="is_active" value="1" <?php if(@$_POST['checkValue'] == 1) echo "checked";  ?>>

Comment: By "keep track of the previous choice", I mean if the user tick the item and submit the first form on the page(supposing there is another submit on the page), and after they submitted (they didn't redirect to another page) the checked checkbox changes back to unchecked. Is there a way to let the checkbox stays checked once it's checked in the first place?

Comment: I think I can use jQuery attr() method to realize this, but the downside is that users can disable JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can still save things to session if you need them later but I recommend just echoing out the previous value.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="headline" id="headline" value="<?php echo $_POST['headline']; ?>" required />

<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Images" name="submit_image"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit_post" value="Submit Your Post"/>
</form>
```

Should you need to compare the previous submissions with what was already submitted then this is one way to do it.

Good work thinking forward :) happy coding